# I was practice problems about tree,I don't understand why the second graph is a tree,isn't the node 4 have two father nodes?

Tags: data-structures

I was practice problems about tree,I don't understand why the second graph is a tree,isn't the node 4 have two father nodes?
The picture's link https://zerojudge.tw/ShowProblem?problemid=b674

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it is not a tree, the task is wrong.

The second graph violates both rule 2. and rule 3.

1.There is exactly one node, called the root, to which no directed edges point.

2.Every node except the root has exactly one edge pointing to it.

3.There is a unique sequence of directed edges from the root to each node.